# Changing Progressbar size within a DrawerLayout

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-studio-3.0, drawerlayout

I am trying to display a Progressbar until my main activity appears. I was able to add a progress bar and it is functioning well. However, I could not change the size of the Progressbar.  Please refer code and screen below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

  <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/sync_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxHeight="55dp"
    android:maxWidth="55dp"
    android:minHeight="15dp"
    android:minWidth="15dp"
    android:visibility="visible" />

   <include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is how it displays:

[image]

I want to make it smaller and centered. Any help or idea would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you can set the style of ProgressBar as **style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"** and set layout gravity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way to satisfy your requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">
   <Linerlayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:gravity="center">
  <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/sync_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxHeight="55dp"
    android:maxWidth="55dp"
    android:minHeight="15dp"
    android:minWidth="15dp"
    android:visibility="visible" />

   <include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</Linerlayout>
   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Milan, However it doesn't work for me. now Progressbar is located over the title bar. I tried with a relative layout and I think I got what I wanted. Anyway thanks for the idea. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should put it (the ProgressBar) inside a RelativeLayout and than you will be able to set size to ProgressBar.

It will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/progressBar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/sync_progress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Keep in mind that this parent view (DrawerLayout) sets its views in hierarchy so the lowest view in the xml will be at the top view hierarchy (Z order) to user. This can cause that the drawer items click wont call. Just put it above the navigation view in the xml.